# I'am error The getter 'token' isn't defined for the type 'LoginResult'. Try importing the library that defines 'token',

Tags: firebase, flutter

```dart
Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.token);

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yywr5.png)

Answer (score 1):

`LoginResult` has an [accessToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface/latest/flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface/LoginResult/accessToken.html) field and not a `token` field.

So update this line:

```dart
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.token);
```

to this:

```dart
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken);
```